# GC overhead limit exceeded to get the rowcount

Tags: java, oracle

Im getting "GC overhead limit exceeded" exception while trying to get rowcount. Could you please let me know what is the issue

Java Code:

```
try{
    rs = RtHelper.getResultSet(hm, sortColumn, sortOrder, con);
    if (rs != null) {
    rs.last();
    rowCountValue = rs.getRow();
    }
    }catch(Exception exception){

    }finally{
    if (rs!=null)
    rs.close();
    }

2014-05-08 00:27:47,948 ==== MYService.java ==== thread: jmsContainer-7349 ==== ERROR >
com....jms.MyService.printException() => (line: 263)
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryERROR: GC overhead limit exceeded
at oracle.jdbc.driver.ScrollableResultSet.cacheCurrentRow(ScrollableResultSet.java:2257)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.ScrollableResultSet.cacheAllRows(ScrollableResultSet.java:2315)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.ScrollableResultSet.getLastRow(ScrollableResultSet.java:2368)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.ScrollableResultSet.last(ScrollableResultSet.java:477)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.last(DelegatingResultSet.java:329)
```

Comment: If you just want the row count, your SQL should be SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table.  This returns just the row count.

Comment: Precisely. This is basically a silly way of getting a row count. It is *O(N)* where it could have been *O(1)* as per @GilbertLeBlanc's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Could be your resultset data size is too large for your available JVM heap memory.

If you have enough RAM, you could increase the Java heap size.
And also if the data is very large retrieve the results in batches.

Add the JVM arguments like this according to your available RAM,

```
-Xms512m -Xmx2g -XX:PermSize=512m  -XX:MaxPermSize=2g
```

This example would allocate a total of 4 gb memory.